# How to specify filepath for celery task logs?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

I have created some REST APIs using Django and I am using Celery to run some asynchronous jobs. The API is defined in `api.py` and the asynchronous job functions are in `actions.py`

Here is what my `api.py` looks like:

```
from myproject import actions

def sample_api(request):
    actions.sample_job.delay()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

Here is what my `actions.py` looks like:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.decorators import task

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@task(name="sample_job")
def sample_job():
    logger.info("start operation")
    <some operations>
    logger.info("stop operation")
```

Now the problem is that I don't know where the logs are getting written. I've tried searching in the project directories and I dont see it anywhere.
I want to provide a path to the log file where these logs should be written. How do I provide a path to the logfile in celery?

(I know there are multiple questions in StackOverflow regarding this. But none really mention how to specify a filepath for the logfile)

Comment: check the worker [configuration](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-f)

Comment: well i have not mentioned any log path in my settings.py. For the api.py i have defined the logger in that file itself and it works. I was hoping the same would work for actions.py too but it didnt

Comment: @Kurohige. Thanks its actually working. I specified --logfile when running celery and i am able to get the logs in the correct location. However only 'info' level logs are coming. i need all categories of logs there. But i think i can google up a solution for this one

Comment: @DejanLekic This is what the page says "choose between DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, or FATAL." But I dont want to chose a single one. i wanted to know how to get all of them in the same logfile.

Comment: anyways thanks i was able to get it to work

Comment: They are LEVELS - DEBUG includes ALL, INFO most of them, WARNING includes warnings and errors, and finally ERROR includes just errors. This is how the Python logging framework works in general...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation you need to specify the log file:

> **-f, --logfile**
>
> *Path to log file. If no logfile is specified, stderr is used.*

for example:

```
celery -A project worker --logfile=<path>
```